# about bernoulli trials and conditional expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Find expected value of number of Bernoulli trials untill consecutive success and failure (SF).

My solution:

Let $X$ be number of trials and let $A$ be event such that they end on success and failure.

$$E[X|A]=\frac{1}{P(A)}\int_AXdP$$

So i wanted to compute P(A)

Let $A_k$ be event such that it ended SF and there were $k$ trials.

$$P(A_k)=p(1-p)\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}(1-p)^jp^{k-2-j}=\frac{p^{k+1}-p^k+p(1-p)^k}{1-2p}$$

$$P(A)=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}P(A_k)$$

But wolfram says it is equal to $1$, I think something is wrong because I did not count events like this: SFSFSFSFSFSFSFSFSF...

However it matches my further solution:

$$\int_AXdP=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}kP(A_k)=\frac{1}{(1-p)p}$$

So the whole expression is equal to $\frac{1}{(1-p)p}$ which is correct answer according to my textbook.

So everything comes down (I think) to whether calcutation of $P(A)$ is correct and why\why not. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: This can be done with states.  It's a Markov process...all we care about is the value of the last state.  Thus you have two active states, according to whether the prior trial was a success or a fail (for the Start state, we can assume that the prior trial was a fail).

Answer (score 1):

Calling the start toss $t$, getting success  $s$, and getting failure  $f$,
we get the following *step by step* Markovian state equations:

eg the first equation shows that with  $1$ step (*toss*), we either get $s$ with a $Pr = \frac12$ or $f$ with a $Pr = \frac12$

$t = 1+\frac12s + \frac12f\tag 1$

$f = 1+\frac12f + \frac12s\tag 2$

$s = 1+\frac12s\; (else\, we\, have\, reached\, sf)\tag 3$

Solving, we get $t = 4$

Comment: In my class we haven't cover Makrov processes yet, can you look at my solution and check it?

Comment: You don't need to know about Markov processes. All you need to know is that if you have tossed $F$, you  either get $F$ again or $S$;  and if you have tossed $S$ you either get $S$ again, or the process ends with $SF$.

Comment: Re your (corrected) formula, the fundamental concept of expectation is $\Sigma {np}$,  so your corrected formula is ok: earlier you were just summing up the probabilities.

Comment: Yes I was summing up the probabilities in order to compute $P(A)$ which is necessary in conditional expectation formula.

Comment: Yea, but you needed to sum up $np$ to get the expectation, which you did later to get the answer. $\frac1{p*(1-p)}$ is the *expectation*, the probability over infinity sums up to $1$, as it did in your initial attempt.

Comment: I wasn't sure about it summing to 1, it seemed strange to me. So $E[X|A]$ is calculated correctly right? In order to get $E[X|A]$ I had to compute $P(A)$ and $\int_AXdP=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}kP(A_k)$ and you say both components are correct right?

Comment: Yes,  exactly. Good work, cheers !$\;\;$ ;)

Comment: I am trying to understand your solution, can you explain it more deeply? For example why we always add 1?

Comment: Okay nevermind, I understood it. Thank you.

Comment: I have added a line, nevertheless for anyone who might come across it who is new to this technique, which is beautifully simple, really.